# codeigniter. delete_files not working when trying to delete image from directory

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, unlink

I am trying to delete an image using a button.

when i click the button i use 
`onClick"'.delete_files(assets/uploads/.$image->filename).'"`

But nothing is happening. The image is still where it was before I clicked the button.
When I do a `print_r($image->filename)` I get the 3 names of my images shown on the page.

this is my code:

```
<table class="images">
    <tr>
    <br/>
    <? foreach($images as $image) { ?>
    <td>
    <a href="assets/uploads/<?= $image->filename ?>" rel="lightbox" title="<?= $image->filename; ?>">
    <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/uploads/<?= $image->filename; ?>" width="200px">
    </a>
<?= '<input type="button" value="Delete" onclick"'.delete_files('assets/uploads/'.$image->filename).'"><br/>'; ?>
    </td>
    <? } ?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I wonder if the path is right. but the assets folder is in my root. httpdocs/assets/uploads and my codeigniter folder is at httpdocs/application/ so that should work.

Comment: You are trying to call a PHP function from the client-side. A client-side action cannot trigger a server-side action without passing data back to the server.

Comment: So what is the right way of doing this? I used this piece of code from a blog I found, but it is not right then.

Comment: you need to issue a $_POST or $_GET request to tell the server to delete it. just make sure to clean the data that is passed because of security reasons..

Comment: so something like if($_GET['delete'] > '')
   { 
    unlink("dir/".$_GET['delete']); 
   } this is just copied from a blog but i don't know how to put that in a button.

Comment: If you put `if($_GET['delete']) { unlink("dir/".$_GET['delete']); }` on a live server, expect very bad times a la `http://yourURL.com/?delete=../../` https://www.owasp.org/index.php/How_to_write_insecure_code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure that you are calling php function on `onclick` attribute of the `button` which is wrong you cannot call directly `server side` functions on the `html element's attribute`

While using `codeigniter` make a function in your controller and place the `anchor` tag instead of button like

```
<table class="images">
<tr>
<br/>
<? foreach($images as $image) { ?>
<td>
<a href="assets/uploads/<?= $image->filename ?>" rel="lightbox" title="<?= $image->filename; ?>">
<img src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/uploads/<?= $image->filename; ?>" width="200px">
</a>

<?= '<a  title="Delete" href="'.site_url().'controller/delete_files/'.$image->filename).'"><br/>'; ?>
</td>
<? } ?>
</tr>
</table>
```

In your controller make a function `delete_files()`

```
 function delete_files($image_name){     
 // write the code to delete or unlink $image_name
 unlink('ROOT PATH'.$image_name);
 }
```

Comment: I tried this.   function delete_files($image_name)
  {
   delete_files('./assets/uploads/'.$image_name);
  
   redirect('home');
  
  }
 but it does not work. What am I missing?

Comment: nevermind i fixed it using $image = $this->uri->segment(3); thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
unlink('./path/to/directory/');
```